# Trading from Pokemon Silver to Crystal impossible?

Tags: game-boy-advance, pokemon-gold-silver-crystal

When I attempt to trade between Silver and Crystal, the trading timeout happens right before I can finish getting my game saved. Help please.
I am using two GBAs, if that makes any difference.

Comment: What link cable are you using? I do seem to recall there being an issue with connecting GB/GBC games by the GBA-Link-Cable (The one with the port in the middle). I seem to recall you need either a [Universal Link Cable](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/gameboyadvance/hook_universallink.jsp) or [**two** GBA Link Cables](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/gameboyadvance/hook_agblink.jsp) hooked up so that each cable is plugged into one GBA, and the other end of each cable is plugged into the middle of the other cable ( sorta like `----<====>----` )

Comment: I have a 4way Link Cable, @TrentHawkins. I know it's not because there's no connection, because when I plug the wrong ends in to the wrong sides, I get "Your freind is not ready" on both ends.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Otherwise, I get "You have to save" or something and when "PLAYER saved the game." appears on one end, I get "Your freind is not ready" on the other.

Comment: [THIS](http://ctrlv.in/914545) doesn't help either... Also it looks just as murky and impossible to see IRL as in the picture.

Comment: I can not say for certain (hence why I am commenting, rather than answering), but I seriously think the issue *might* be related to using the 4way, as it is likely a 3rd generation cable: "[This link cable can only be used for connecting Game Link compatible Game Boy Advance games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Link_Cable#Third_generation)". It might allow for a brief 'handshake' to occur, but once it tries to send data - the system is receiving packets on communication lines the GB/GBC games don't know exist.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Wait, isn't the GBA and GBC the same link port?